# Сообщение об успешном действии ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Надо оповещать пользователя об успешном действии (например: добавлении в бд). На данный момент использую `TempData`.

**View:**

```
@if (TempData["Success"] != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
        <strong>Success!</strong> 
        <p>@TempData["Success"]</p>
    </div>
}
```

Но я хочу сделать зеленый всплывающий alert в правой нижней части экрана. Это надо делать на JS. Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:** Какой фреймвок использовать и как сделать проверку на успешное добавление на JS?

Comment: [tag:ajax] вам в помощь

Comment: [alertifyjs](http://alertifyjs.com/) и [notifyjs](https://notifyjs.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал плагин [iziToast](https://github.com/dolce/iziToast). Посылаю `ajax` запрос, в зависимости от результата посылаю разные `alert'ы`.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(phone),
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data) {
            iziToast.show({
                title: 'Added!',
                color: 'green',
                message: 'Added successfully!'
            });
        },
        error: function() {
           iziToast.show({
              title: 'Error!',
              color: 'red',
              message: 'An error occurred while processing your request.'
           });
        }
});
```